# add values into textbox while loop is running asynchronously asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I add values into textbox and display them while loop is running for long process in asp.net C#

for example

```
private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      for(int i=1; i<=100; i++)
      {
//do some work such as add values into db
//then display values on each iteration
        textBox2.Text = i.ToString();

      }

    }
```

Comment: Do you want to append text one by one to the textbox..?

Comment: I need to find a way maybe in ajax to display every one on page while the process is running

Answer (score 1):

According to you if you want all data in one textbox then do as below code..

```
private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      for(int i=1; i<=100; i++)
      {
        textBox2.Text += i.ToString()+" ";
      }    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with ASP.NET is that your process will not be refreshed everytime you update the `textBox2.Text` property. Instead, it will only show you the last action performed because the HTML will only be rendered and sent at the very end.

There are some workarounds you can take around this solution, but they use AJAX and asynchronous calls.

I was faced with a similar situation and what I did was launching the process with an AJAX call. Then, when I needed to update the status, I would change a value in the Session object and have the an AJAX call update the status on the client side regularly. Maybe are there any better solutions however.

Comment: Can you send me a sample of what you did?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't. It was for my work and I don't even work there anymore. However, the concept should give you an idea of how to proceed.